# comando em Powershell para listar membros

Tags: powershell

Alguém já se deparou com essa situação, comando em power shell para listar membros do AD conectados a impressora compartilhada em cada setor.

Comment: Já viu isso aqui? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852274%28v=wps.630%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396